# Is there a way to see the final page address in the url preview?

Tags: browser, url, url-shortening

Usually when you hover cursor above a url, the link hint appears in the lower left/right corner of the browser window. These days people use link shorteners which don't allow to see what the target page is. Sometimes links are shortened several times (because of reasons). You ought to visit the link, be redirected and at the end of the journey you may see the final address link.
lting link. Still, it may have been shortened before, which is not actually helping.

---

My browser of choice is Firefox, but I'm also interested in solutions for other browsers.

Comment: I wrote for myself a Google Mobilizer Bookmarklet - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html The bookmarklet makes Google Mobilizer get just the content of the shortened URLs. You can tweak the code to let it show images along with content.

Answer (score 0):

*(I don’t know/tested any of these.)*

There are some Firefox add-ons that might help here:

- [Long URL Please Mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/long-url-please-mod/)
- [Long URL Please](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/long-url-please/) (uses the service http://www.longurlplease.com/)
- [LongURL Mobile Expander](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/longurl-mobile-expander/) (uses the service http://longurl.org/)

There are also userscripts:

- [LongURL Mobile Expander](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/32115)
- [Untiny](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/35276/) (uses the service http://untiny.me/)